# Not able to rename root user of MySQL

Tags: linux, mysql

As part of security hardening, I wanted to remove/rename  root user of mysql. While trying I get an `error mysql.procs_priv doesn't exist.`
what is the significance of 'mysql.procs_priv'? Is it mandatory to have this table in mysql db? Is there any side effect if I use UPDATE query to change username (looks like user is a table like any other table in DB) ?

```
mysql> RENAME USER root TO newroot;
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'mysql.procs_priv' doesn't exist
mysql> show tables;
+-----------------+
| Tables_in_mysql |
+-----------------+
| columns_priv    | 
| db              | 
| func            | 
| host            | 
| tables_priv     | 
| user            | 
+-----------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Try to run `mysql_upgrade`. Possibly your tables are deprecated after a mysql upgrade.

Comment: mysql_upgrade didn't work. Also after upgrade procs_priv table is not getting created. I am using Val0x00f method to change user name

Comment: @jofel, I was trying to reply for your comment,but due to some error i could not, that is why late reply. I have asked in Meta forum for same [link](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3451/error-while-submitting-comment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To rename mysql `root` user to `newroot`, follow the following steps. I've tested here!

1. Log in as root first using `mysql -u root -p`
2. `grant all privileges on *.* to 'tempuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'somepass';`
3. `flush privileges;`
4. `quit`
5. Log back in as the `tempuser` as follow: `mysql -u tempuser -psomepass`
6. `update mysql.user set user='newroot' where user = 'root';`
7. `quit`
8. Log back in as `mysql -u newroot -p` and use the `root`s original password.

Comment: I am new to mysql,  Is this a standard way to rename user, any side effect? I am suspecting because there is already one 'RENAME USER' statement available .

Comment: Well, `rename user` command is introduced after mysql 5.0.2 version. You can check your version from the terminal using `mysql -u newroot -p -e 'select version();'`  I personally believe that this is the best practice to rename root user. Thus, first creating a temp user and then rename the root user from there.